# regular expression to build span tags using multiple patterns

Tags: javascript, regex

Apart from what they are, I dont know anything about regular expressions... :(

I have this code in a javascript function:

```
var foroFormatting = function (text) {
    var newText = text;
    var findreps = [
        { find: /^([^\-]+) \- /g, rep: '<span class="ui-selectmenu-item-header">$1</span>' },
        { find: /([^\|><]+) \| /g, rep: '<span class="ui-selectmenu-item-content">$1</span>' },
        { find: /([^\|><\(\)]+) (\()/g, rep: '<span class="ui-selectmenu-item-content">$1</span>$2' },
        { find: /([^\|><\(\)]+)$/g, rep: '<span class="ui-selectmenu-item-content">$1</span>' },
        { find: /(\([^\|><]+\))$/g, rep: '<span class="ui-selectmenu-item-footer">$1</span>' }
    ];
    for (var i in findreps) {
        newText = newText.replace(findreps[i].find, findreps[i].rep);
    }
    return newText;
}
```

This code expect a string like this

```
John Doe - 78 West Main St Apt 3A | Bloomsburg, PA 12345 (footer text)
```

and split it in four span elements right?

I would like to apply the same formatting to a string that is a bit different from that

```
John Doe - 78 West Main St Apt 3A | Bloomsburg, PA 12345
```

How do I have to modify the regular expression?

**EDIT**

I am trying to use [this plugin](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/selectmenu/index.html) (third example) with a string of mine that is different from the original just in the last part

Comment: what is your desired result? you want to have empty `<span class="ui-selectmenu-item-footer" />` ?

Comment: please have a look to my edit at the end of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are dropping is just `(footer text)`, then the same function without the last replacement regex will work.

```
var foroFormatting2 = function (text) {
    var newText = text;
    var findreps = [
        { find: /^([^\-]+) \- /g, rep: '<span class="ui-selectmenu-item-header">$1</span>' },
        { find: /([^\|><]+) \| /g, rep: '<span class="ui-selectmenu-item-content">$1</span>' },
        { find: /([^\|><\(\)]+)$/g, rep: '<span class="ui-selectmenu-item-content">$1</span>' }
    ];
    for (var i in findreps) {
        newText = newText.replace(findreps[i].find, findreps[i].rep);
    }
    return newText;
}
```

I've removed the parts that captured and formatted `(footer text)`. I suggest reading up on [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). They are a great tool.

Comment: No problem. Keep in mind the answer by **mykhal**. After looking at the original function, this may indeed be true. However, the resulting `<span>` set may not be what you what - i.e. class of `footer` still appears.

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to change anything, the code works perfectly without the footer text in parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

Well, let me give you some tips to make this super easy.  Change your input format to this.

This is an array of strings in JSON format.

```
var arr = ['John Doe', '78 West Main St Apt 3A', 'Bloomsburg, PA 12345', '(footer text)'];
var outputStr = '<span class="ui-selectmenu-item-header">' + 
       //This line concats the array elements with this text inserted
       // between each element
       arr.join('</span><span class="ui-selectmenu-item-header">') + 
'</span>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered modifying the input format, maybe JSON?  That looks like a very flimsy parsing format.

What exactly is the expected output?  Use the required spans